# Django - How to filter database using HTML select tag?

Tags: django, filter, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create an E-Commerce Website. So, I am trying to add filters like **Price: Low - to High** and vice versa. I know how to filter the price but I don't know how to apply the filter on select value getting changed.

**Here is HTML Code**

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <label>
        <select class="bg-dark" name="price" id="priceFilter">
            <option value="normal">Sort by Price</option>
            <option value="low">Low-to-High</option>
            <option value="high">High-to-Low</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Django Code**

```
def index(request):
    fil = request.GET('price')
    if fil == "low":
        products = Product.objects.all().order_by('productDiscountedPrice')
    elif fil == "high":
        products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-productDiscountedPrice')
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'products': products
    }
    return render(request, "Amazon/index.html", context)
```

So, How to sort products when `select tag` value gets changed?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use ajax if you don't want to reload the page. Here is the [ajax tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) link.
- Include this [jquery link](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) in the main html page head tag.

  ```
       <script>
           $('#priceFilter').on('change', 'input, select', function(event){
           // id = this.id; // you can use this.id to get the corresponding id.

               var word = $("#priceFilter").val();

               $.ajax({ 
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: '{% url <YOUR DJANGO INDEX VIEW URL NAME> %}',
                   data: {
                       word: word,
                   },
                   success: function (response) { 
                       console.log(response); // print response.content and response.data to see the data in the console. And later you can use those data in template using javascript.
                   },
                   error: function (error_data) {
                       console.log(error_data)
                   }
               });

          }
       </script>
  ```

And in the views.py, write modify your view like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    fil = request.GET('price')
    if fil:
        if fil == "low":
            products = Product.objects.all().order_by('productDiscountedPrice')
        elif fil == "high":
            products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-productDiscountedPrice')
        else:
            products = Product.objects.all()
        context = {
            'products': products
        }
        return JsonResponse(context)
    else:
        context = {}
        return render(request, "Amazon/index.html", context)
```